# problem with using SQL CTE function inside prestashop

Tags: php, sql, statistics, prestashop, common-table-expression

I have a problem with using WITH function (CTE) in prestashop 1.7.6.9 to make additional features in stats.

My original PHP code (works fine):

```
$this->query = 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.reference, p.id_product, pl.name,
            ROUND(AVG(od.product_price / o.conversion_rate), 2) as avgPriceSold,
            LEFT(MAX(o.date_add), 10) AS date,
            IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) as quantity,
            IFNULL(SUM(od.product_quantity), 0) AS totalQuantitySold,
            ROUND(IFNULL(SUM((od.product_price * od.product_quantity) / o.conversion_rate), 0), 2) AS totalPriceSold,
            1 + LEAST( TO_DAYS('.$array_date_between[1].'), TO_DAYS(NOW())) - GREATEST(TO_DAYS( '.$array_date_between[0].'), TO_DAYS(product_shop.date_add)) - IFNULL((
                SELECT COUNT(sh.quantity) FROM `ps1769_xcustom_stock_history` sh WHERE sh.quantity <= 0 AND sh.id = p.id_product AND sh.date BETWEEN '.$date_between.'
                GROUP BY sh.id
            ),0) AS AvailableDays,
            p.wholesale_price AS purchasePrice,
            product_shop.active
            FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product p
            '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').'
            LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang pl ON (p.id_product = pl.id_product AND pl.id_lang = '.(int)$this->getLang().' '.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl').')
            LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'order_detail od ON od.product_id = p.id_product
            LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'orders o ON od.id_order = o.id_order
            '.Shop::addSqlRestriction(Shop::SHARE_ORDER, 'o').'
            '.Product::sqlStock('p', 0).'
            WHERE o.valid = 1
            AND o.invoice_date BETWEEN '.$date_between.'
            GROUP BY od.product_id';

if (Validate::IsName($this->_sort)) {
        $this->query .= ' ORDER BY `'.bqSQL($this->_sort).'`';
        if (isset($this->_direction) && Validate::isSortDirection($this->_direction)) {
            $this->query .= ' '.$this->_direction;
        }
}

if (($this->_start === 0 || Validate::IsUnsignedInt($this->_start)) && Validate::IsUnsignedInt($this->_limit)) {
        $this->query .= ' LIMIT '.(int)$this->_start.', '.(int)$this->_limit;
}
```

I just add one table using WITH function **without using it** (just for test) like this:

```
$this->query = 'WITH LastDates30 AS (
                   SELECT id, date, row_num
                   FROM
                        (
                            SELECT id, date,
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) AS row_num
                            FROM
                                '._DB_PREFIX_.'xcustom_stock_history sh
                            WHERE
                                quantity > 0
                        ) AS subquery
                    WHERE row_num <= 30
                )
                SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.reference, p.id_product, pl.name,
                ROUND(AVG(od.product_price / o.conversion_rate), 2) as avgPriceSold,
                LEFT(MAX(o.date_add), 10) AS date,
                IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) as quantity,
                IFNULL(SUM(od.product_quantity), 0) AS totalQuantitySold,
                ROUND(IFNULL(SUM((od.product_price * od.product_quantity) / o.conversion_rate), 0), 2) AS totalPriceSold,
                1 + LEAST( TO_DAYS('.$array_date_between[1].'), TO_DAYS(NOW())) - GREATEST(TO_DAYS( '.$array_date_between[0].'), TO_DAYS(product_shop.date_add)) - IFNULL((
                    SELECT COUNT(sh.quantity) FROM `ps1769_xcustom_stock_history` sh WHERE sh.quantity <= 0 AND sh.id = p.id_product AND sh.date BETWEEN '.$date_between.'
                    GROUP BY sh.id
                ),0) AS AvailableDays,
                p.wholesale_price AS purchasePrice,
                product_shop.active
                FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product p
                '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').'
                LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang pl ON (p.id_product = pl.id_product AND pl.id_lang = '.(int)$this->getLang().' '.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl').')
                LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'order_detail od ON od.product_id = p.id_product
                LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'orders o ON od.id_order = o.id_order
                '.Shop::addSqlRestriction(Shop::SHARE_ORDER, 'o').'
                '.Product::sqlStock('p', 0).'
                WHERE o.valid = 1
                AND o.invoice_date BETWEEN '.$date_between.'
                GROUP BY od.product_id';

    if (Validate::IsName($this->_sort)) {
        $this->query .= ' ORDER BY `'.bqSQL($this->_sort).'`';
        if (isset($this->_direction) && Validate::isSortDirection($this->_direction)) {
            $this->query .= ' '.$this->_direction;
        }
    }

    if (($this->_start === 0 || Validate::IsUnsignedInt($this->_start)) && Validate::IsUnsignedInt($this->_limit)) {
        $this->query .= ' LIMIT '.(int)$this->_start.', '.(int)$this->_limit;
    }
```

Even I not use this additional table it returns empty table :(

I test this SQL query outside prestashop script and it works properly.
I think that the problem is with CTE in PHP, but I have no idea why?

Comment: You could try adding a semi-colon - ie. ; - just before your "WITH", and see if that does the trick.  If PHP is sending some other command statement of its own before executing your actual query, then SQL might not be interpreting everything correctly